Can I apply for DS 160 online while I am in another country and attend interview in my country?
I've completed the DS-160 form online for my USA visa renewal and received confirmation. However, I'm currently in India and have scheduled my interview in my home country and I will be there for the interview next week. Will this be accepted, considering I filled out the application while in a different country? or should I fill a new application DS-160 from my home country altogether?

Are you currently travelling / on holiday or are you living in India and going back home for a visit?

It's perfectly fine, I know personally of many people who do that. Usually people fill DS-160 while in the US and then travel to Canada for stamping, it's a pretty standard process. As long as all the information is correct and you submitted it to the right visa post (which it sounds like you did, since you have an appointment confirmation), you should be good.
